# Post customs objects to web with NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: ios, nsdata, nsobject, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm trying to post to a server some objects. The objects are encode following the NSCoding protocol.

I know that I have to convert those objects to NSData and use NSMutableURLRequest for post them.

But looks that is not possible to post them as objects and the server to understand. If it possible at all or should I append every variable of the objects to the nsdata before posting?

I'm tried to set the content type to text/xml, multipart/form-data and to application/url-encoding without any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helped with RestKit or ASIHTTP libraries.